# Key to boot from USB on Ubuntu MacBook Air

Tags: usb, startup, unix, formatting

Recently, I removed OS X from my MacBook Air and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

I have been trying to install Debian during last week, but I don't have idea what's the key to enter into 'BIOS boot options' to boot from pendrive.

Comment: C for 'external boot' Opt for a choice - https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201255

Comment: how about ALT? ;)

Comment: alt == opt... it's the same key

Answer (score 1):

hold the C key to boot from any media(s)

Comment: Doesn't work, when I hold the C key, it dispays a grey screen during some seconds and after starts from sda1 and load my os.

Comment: if C doesn't work, your device is not bootable

Comment: Option. If that don't work, then worry about bootability

Comment: worked with Alt.